# Standard template fields not showing in inherited templates

Tags: sitecore-commerce, templates

I have created a template which inherits the standard template. Then I created an item using this template but the item not showing any fields from the standard template. Is there anything more I need to do to get the standard template's field in the item?

Comment: Have you enabled "Show standard fields"? https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2014/11/how-to-view-standard-fields-in-sitecore-cms/

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the "Standard fields" option in the "View" ribbon.
[image: show standard fields]